# Not clicking on element after class specifically called

Tags: puppeteer

For some reason I'm not able to click on an element that appears on a screen with puppeteer js.
Here is the code:

```
  const getAllElements = await page.$$('._1Nk0C');

  for (let [i, link] of getAllElements.entries()) {
    try {
      await link.click();
      await sleep.sleep(4);
      await link.click('._1NHYN _3d86A Ddtb4');
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }
```

Here I find all elements with `'._1Nk0C'`
It then clicks on the element which as it enlarge in forefront. `await link.click();`
I then try to click the button on screen.  I can confirm this is on the screen.

```
await link.click('._1NHYN _3d86A Ddtb4');
```

Nothing happens.  It doesn't error out just doesn't click on element.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`elementHandle.click([options])` does not accept a selector as an argument. If you're trying to click on an element in the page based on its selector try:

```js
await link.click();
await sleep.sleep(4);
await page.click(selector);
```